# Constantly getting org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne references an unknown entity: error

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I can successfully insert records into the tables using the Db2 console.

```
INSERT INTO db2admin.school VALUES (1, 'BJS');

INSERT INTO db2admin.STUDENT VALUES (1, 'Pankaj', 30, 1);
```

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.School (school_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name varchar(128));

create table DB2ADMIN.Student (student_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT null, name varchar(128) not null, age smallint not null, school_id int NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (school_id) REFERENCES School(school_id));
```

One School can contain many students. Here is how I am defining the entity relationships in Hibernate 5.4.18.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public  class   School
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SchoolIdSequence", schema="db2admin", sequenceName = "Sequence_School", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SchoolIdSequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school")
    //@JoinColumn(name="student_id", nullable=false)
    private Set<Student> students;

    public School()
    {}

    public School(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Set getStudents()
    {
        return students;
    }
 
    public void setStudents(Set students)
    {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "School [Name = '" + name + "']";
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public  class   Student
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceStudentId", sequenceName  = "Sequence_Student", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceStudentId")
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="school_id", nullable=false)
    private School school;
    
    public Student() 
    {}

    public Student(String name, int age, School school)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.school = school;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", Name=" + name + ", Age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

I get the following error on executing the application.

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on org.jfa.persistence.hibernate.entity.Student.school references an unknown entity: org.jfa.persistence.hibernate.entity.School
```

I have tried to tweak the relationship settings in the class in different ways as suggested by others on Internet/StackOverFlow. Yet, no luck so far. Please help.

Comment: are both classes annotated with `@Entety`

Comment: Sometimes entities are imported from wrong packages by mistake, Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307824/use-of-onetomany-or-manytomany-targeting-an-unmapped-class-exception-occuring/62308459#62308459

Comment: Alexander, yes they are annotated with ```@Entity```.

Comment: @JoinColumn should be defined in one side remove it from OneToMany side

Comment: Did you try using mappedBy on OneToMany?

Comment: check value of `name` property in School.java entity class.

Comment: @tashkhisi, I tried this without luck. @OneToMany(mappedBy="school", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Your Student and School class are public and in seperate files?

Comment: @tashkhisi, yes they are public and in separate files.

Comment: There is no problem with your relations, it seems that School  Class can not be mapped by hibernate, delete Student class temproraily and check if you can  add a row to database using your School entity.

Comment: Also put your both Classes completely here in your question with all mapping in place

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly referenced school_id instead of student_id in School.java. It should be:

```
class School
{
   ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id", nullable=false)
    private Set<Student> students;

   ...
}
```

Comment: It does not help.